# How to redirect after form submission in contact form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress, soap-client, contact-form

I am using contact form 7 to submit a form and generate a reference number through soap client using the wpcf7_before_send_mail.

The code is

```
function wpcf7_do_something($WPCF7_ContactForm)
{

    if (3490 == $WPCF7_ContactForm->id()) {
      $client = new SoapClient('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/4dwsdl', array('trace' => 1));
   $res_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('01 feb 2015'));
   $enquiry_id = $client->__call('WS_AddContact',  
       array(
           'narwal Devender',
           null,
           'Devender',
           'narwal',
           'hisar',
           'Hisar',
           'Haryana',
           '125001',
           'Australia',
           '01662246138',
           '9802260750',
           '8529000369',
           'vijaylal@webmastershisar.com',
           true,
           'google',
           'google',
           'Phone Call',
           0,
           'type of good should be strode.',
           $res_date,
           '2 to 6  Months',
           'SSPSS',
           null,//array('xxxxxxx'),
           array('46.75'),
           array('1 x 1 x 1 (1qm)'),
           array('xxxxxxxxx'),
           array('send print should be here to work.'),
           null,
           'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
           null
       )
   );


   mail('vijaylal@webmastershisar.com', 'My Subject', $enquiry_id); 

  }
  return $wpcf7;
}
```

This is working fine and sending email.

But I want to show the enquiry id to the custom on thankyou page or any page or by using some redirect and sending data to the url.

I am also trying to use this code in wpcf7_mail_sent this also work,

But when I am trying to use redirect It does nothing and contact form hangs simply.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_redirect_on_submit');

function wpcf7_redirect_on_submit($wpcf7)
{
        header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' );
        exit;
}
```

How can I redirect contact form in wpcf7_mail_sent without using javascript or jQuery on_sent_ok?

or

**How can I show this Enquiry id to the user on a page?**

Can anybody please help to get this work done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also used an available hook to change properties

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_contact_form_properties', 'let_me_redirect', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Add the code that will run when on_sent_ok is triggered;
 */
function let_me_redirect( $properties, $contact_form_obj){
 $properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .="on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('http://www.google.com');\""
 ;
 return $properties;
}
```

Comment: It was just an example of what we can do. I changed the code. Now check

Comment: Dear you were right , I am just close to result but I was just want to insert that $userid in my url like `$properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .="on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('http://soandso.com/thankyou/?enquryid='".$key_1_value.");\"";` but this not working

Comment: did you add value to $key_1_value? coz it is working for me

Comment: Thanks dear you save ma ass. the right string is '$properties[ 'additional_settings' ] .="on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('http://soandso.com/thankyou/?enquryid=".$key_1_value."');\""
 ; ' . I was doing some mistake in string.

Comment: Though this is not the right way what I was asking...I do some jugad by updating user meta in wpcf7_before_send_mail and get user meta in wpcf7_contact_form_properties.

Comment: **Warning:** This method is going to get [removed from CF7](https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/): *"Note: The method using on_sent_ok hook is no longer recommended. This function is scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017."*